# what causes a large upstream_header_time in nginx?

Tags: nginx, amazon-elb

Setup:

```
Angular / Django / Nginx in ECS.

Route 53 -> ELB -> Target group ECS

With Nginx proxying /api | /admin calls to Django.
```

We have a large lag or delay on some of our API requests with the following log being shown: (Line broken for easier reading)

```
timestamp="16/Jul/2019:16:24:43 +0000" 
client=10.96.192.168 
request="GET /api/redacted/?
redacted=0&
redacted=52.895649&
redacted=53.226591&
redacted=-2.900391&
redacted=-1.873169 HTTP/1.1" 
request_length=919 
bytes_sent=200514 
body_bytes_sent=200245 
referer=https://redacted.redacted.redacted.redacted.redacted/redacted 
user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36" 
upstream_addr=127.0.0.1:8000 
upstream_status=200 
request_time=19.077 
upstream_response_time=19.064 
upstream_connect_time=0.000 
upstream_header_time=19.064 
app_db_read_time=- 
app_db_write_time=- 
app_analysis_time=- 
app_other_time=-
```

what has caught our eye as the main delay is the `upstream_header_time` and `upstream_response_time` being around 20 seconds!.

However being new to Nginx I have no idea where to start to debug this, working locally everything works as expected with no delay like this.

**Question:** What is causing this large 20 second upstream header / response time?

Config File: https://gist.github.com/jackdh/4fdffe6b11799f544d7cb211cc66bfe2

Thanks

Comment: hi @jackdh, did you found out in the end? I have a similar issue.

Comment: Hey @AlexandruR it did turn out to be my backend causing the issue. I had a reverse proxy on the django server which collapsed under the strain and caused the whole middleware to hang. Very annoying as it didn't throw any errors, I had to strip out API's until I found the one causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm profiling upstream server code as well for it. Although I set a header right after I get the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the NGINX docs:

```
$upstream_header_timekeeps time spent on receiving the response header from the upstream server (1.7.10); the time is kept in seconds with millisecond resolution. Times of several responses are separated by commas and colons like addresses in the $upstream_addr variable.
```

So that's your Python backend taking forever to answer.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html